# Where can i find a realiable English to German translator

Tags: translation, english-to-german, resource

I am writing a fanfiction of Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha. Since the Belkan Language is identified to be German i want to be able to reliably translate a number of spells which have english names to german. ie [these spells](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Nanoha_Takamachi#Spells) because Hayate's Collect and Use would allow her access to Nanoha's Pre-StrikerS spells.

i tried [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/de/shooter) and [translate.reference](http://translate.reference.com/translate?query=accel&src=en&dst=de) to try and translate the name of [this spell](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Axel_Shooter) prepared to translate each individual word, however i got different results ie.

i tried accel and axel in google and got nothing, on translate.reference i got Grafikbeschleuniger and Axelsprung beim Eiskunstlauf retrospectively.

i am wondering if there is a reliable English to German translator which i can use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Comment: I'm afraid that the answer is no - there is no reliable automatic translation service. What's more, for something like 2-5 word names I dare to say that it is not possible to create one, because it would have to guess which meaning of each word should be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good online translator for single words is [this one](http://dict.leo.org).
If you just want a 1:1 translation, it may be good enough, however even this does not excuse you completely from thinking ;-)

And even the best translator has no feeling for a language.
For instance, "accel" is surely derived from "acceleration", what is "Beschleunigung" in German, in this context. 
However nobody would ever consider "Beschleunigungs Schütze" as a good name for a spell!

My suggestion:
 Look for an imagi-native German. Otherwise there's a high risk that the  spells sound very strange to any German native speaker.

Comment: As you pointed out, if he doesn't speak German it's very likely that the translations doesn't sound good nor correct at all since there are words in English with different meanings. An usual example is the word curious.